# script that counts the fraction of Alphabet (a, b, c) every 5 lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file which contain list of IP address, and Ш need to count specific IP address repeated in every 5 lines.

```
74.125.227.31        
74.125.229.87        
173.194.39.56         
173.194.39.56        
74.125.232.216       
173.194.39.56          
74.125.239.31         
173.194.39.56         
74.125.227.31         
74.125.227.31       
74.125.239.23         
173.194.34.120        
74.125.227.31        
74.125.239.23        
74.125.239.23
```

Expected output is: (Every five lines it counts the number `173.194.39.56` repeated. I mean in the above list, in the first five lines the IP address `173.194.39.56` repeated 2 times. and in the second five lines it repeated 2 times,and in the last five lines it will be found zero times)

```
IP Address                     count   
173.194.39.56                    2       
173.194.39.56                    2  
173.194.39.56                    0
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please rephrase/explain

Comment: What do you mean by alphabet(a, b, c)? Is it only one IP address that you want to count?

Comment: Actually, SO is not a code generator - what have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

data = ['74.125.227.31', '74.125.229.87', '173.194.39.56', 
'173.194.39.56', '74.125.232.216', '173.194.39.56', 
'74.125.239.31', '173.194.39.56', '74.125.227.31', 
'74.125.227.31', '74.125.239.23', '173.194.34.120', 
'74.125.227.31', '74.125.239.23', '74.125.239.23']

ip = '173.194.39.56'
formatstr = "{:<16}{:>8}"
print formatstr.format('IP Address', 'count')

paginated = [data[start:end] for start, end in 
        zip(range(0,len(data),5), range(5, len(data), 5)+[None])]
for chunk in paginated: 
    print formatstr.format(ip, Counter(chunk)[ip])
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```
with open('input.txt') as fl:
  f = fl.read().split()

f = [f[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(f),5)]

s = '173.194.39.56'

for i in f:
  print i.count(s)

[OUTPUT]
2
2
0
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way if you have read your file into a python list is to use the Counter function from the collections library.

I've made a simple example:

```
from collections import Counter
from pprint import print


#I've just put this here for showing how it works. you can replace this with
#reading the data from a file
ips = ['74.125.227.31', '74.125.229.87', '173.194.39.56', '173.194.39.56', '74.125.232.216', '173.194.39.56', '74.125.239.31', '173.194.39.56', '74.125.227.31', '74.125.227.31', '74.125.239.23', '173.194.34.120', '74.125.227.31', '74.125.239.23', '74.125.239.23']

#this is an example how you can read the lines from your file. just replace the file name
ips = [line.strip() for line in open('ip.txt')]

#this does the magic: Counter(ips)
pprint (Counter(ips))

# and this is the result as a dict
{'173.194.34.120': 1,
 '173.194.39.56': 4,
 '74.125.227.31': 4,
 '74.125.229.87': 1,
 '74.125.232.216': 1,
 '74.125.239.23': 3,
 '74.125.239.31': 1}`
```

If you are on linux or unix and the thing doesn't need to be in python there is another very easy way to do so:

```
 cat ip.txt | tr -d ' '| sort | uniq -c | sort -n
   1 173.194.34.120
   1 74.125.229.87
   1 74.125.232.216
   1 74.125.239.31
   3 74.125.239.23
   4 173.194.39.56
   4 74.125.227.31
```